# load only components scripts that are in the current page

Tags: aem

What I'm trying to achieve is that if i have 2 components nodes :

- component1

  - clientlib

    - component1.js
- component2

  - clientlib

    - component2.js

and i drag them into page1, then when page1 is generated, only component1.js and component2.js will be loaded when navigating to page1 .

One approach i saw is to use custom `Tag Library` as described here : http://www.icidigital.com/blog/best-approaches-clientlibs-aem-part-3/

I have two questions :

1) is there an existing feature in AEM to do this ?

2) if not, what is the easiest way to create such custom `Tag Library` ?

EDIT:

Assume that there is no ability to just include all component clientLibs, rather load only those that are added to the page.

Comment: This is available out of the box in AEM. Here is the [official documentation for AEM 6.2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics/clientlibs.html) and is applicable to previous versions also.

Comment: it only described how to load scripts of specific category.. i cannot find reference to HOW TO load the scripts of components that are in the current page, so other scripts of components with the same category which are not in that page will not be loaded, ty

Comment: Component specific scripts should be defined with unique category corresponding to that component. So that when you use the same component across pages, those scripts are included. If you give a common category to multiple components' scripts, then they should be providing some common functionality across all those components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in feature to do this. Although I've heard that the clientlib infrastructure is being looked at for a re-write so I'm optimistic that something like this will be added in the future.

We have, and I know other company have, created a "deferred script tag." Ours is a very simple tag that take a chunk of html like a clientlib include, add it to a unique list and then on an out call at the footer, spits it all out one after another.

Here's the core of a simple tag implementation that extends BodyTagSupport. Then in your footer grab the attribute and write it out.

```
public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    SlingHttpServletRequest request = (SlingHttpServletRequest)pageContext.getAttribute("slingRequest");

    Set<String> delayed = (Set<String>)request.getAttribute(DELAYED_INCLUDE);

    if(delayed == null){
        delayed = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.bodyContent.getString())){
        delayed.add(this.bodyContent.getString().trim());
    }

    request.setAttribute(DELAYED_INCLUDE, delayed);
    return EVAL_PAGE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the possible way of doing is to write script in your page component/abstract page component that does something like this -

Step1 : String path = currentPage.getPath()

Step2 : Query this path for components (one way is to have a master list do a contains clause on sling:resourceType)

Step 3: User resource resolver to resolve the resourceType in Step 3, this will give  you resource under your apps.

Step 4: From the above resource get the sub-resource with primary type as cq:ClientLibraryFolder

Step 5: from the client libs resource in Step 4 get the categories and include the JS from them

you could actually write a model to adapt a component resource to a clientLibrary to actually clean the code.

Let me know if you need actual code, I can write that in my free time.